# Uniform Convergence of a serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove that

$$\eta(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{z}} $$

does not converge uniformly on A = { z | Re $z$ > 1 }

I don't know how to proceed with this exercise. Could anyone explain me why I cannot use the Weierstrass M test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the summation index should be $n$, not $i$?

Comment: Why don't you try using the Weierstrass $M$-test and see what happens? If you don't see what goes wrong, explain your attempt and we can help you understand.

Comment: My guess is that you meant $n=1$ instead of $n=0$.

Comment: By using the Weierstrass M test, I proved the uniform convergence on closed disks in A, but not on all of A

Comment: Note though that the series converges uniformly in each region $\Omega_a= \{z:\,\Re(z)>a\}$, for each $a>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Weierstrass $M$-test because $\sup_{z\in A}\left|\frac1{n^z}\right|=\frac1n$ and the harmonic series diverges.

And the convergence is not uniform because when a series of bounded functions converges, its sum is bounded too. But $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to1^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^z}=\infty$.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: another way is to show that the partial sums from $N$ to $2N$ when $z=1+1/\log N$ do not converge to zero as $N \to \infty$ so the series is not uniform Cauchy